# adding library to my app

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, libraries

I'm trying to add this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3703 but there is some thing wrong ,filters and not working and gives illegalstateexception, how to solve that  ?
edit : 
don't add it manually add the link on the gradle file

Comment: No. NDK isn't needed. I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478933/adding-https-android-arsenal-com-details-1-3703-library/44478940#44478940 is a correct answer.

Comment: I've did that but all library classes are on red !! and codes aren't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
}
```

Then add this line in the activity where you want to use the library

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeImageProcessor");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added this line but classes all classes are on red and the filters aren't working @fn5341

Comment: Try with Build -> Clean Project. Then Build -> Rebuild Project. I updated the answer, add the last block of code that I wrote

Comment: when i use Filter myFilter = new Filter();
        myFilter.addSubFilter(new SaturationSubfilter(1.3f));
        Bitmap outputImage = myFilter.processFilter(bm);
        im.setImageBitmap(outputImage); i get java.lang.IllegalStateException